# Matching and counting leading whitespaces in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am fairly new to regexes and i got a little problem with counting (only leading) whitespaces in a string.
Let's say i got a string that looks like this:

```
my $str="        for getopts :h opt;; do       #this is just a comment";
```

and now i only want to count the leading spaces / tabs in this string. No changing of the original string - just counting.

I tried something like this (i know that's pretty trivial):

```
my $count =()= $str =~ /"^[\\t]|^\\s+"/gm;
```

But unfortunately this counts of course just the first whitespace in this string.
Anybody got an idea ?

Comment: That regex does not do what you think it does. It matches either: A double quote `"` followed by newline, followed by either a backslash `\\ ` or `t`, OR newline/beginning of string followed by backslash `\\ ` followed by one or more `s` followed by a double quote `"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear whether your string is

```
'my $str="        for getopts :h opt;; do       #this is just a comment";'
```

or just

```
'        for getopts :h opt;; do       #this is just a comment'
```

but I'm assuming the latter. However there aren't any double quotes in that string so your regex will fail because it requires them.

I can't get your statement to do anything useful. Do you realise that `\\s` and `\\t` within a regex means the literal characters backslash `\` and `s` or `t`, and not the metacharacters for whitespace and tab?

An alternative way that you probably won't understand is

```
my $count = () = $str =~ /\G\s/g;
```

which works by putting the global match in list context so that all the leading spaces are found one by one, and then putting that list in scalar context to return its length.

However the easiest and most obvious way is to capture all the whitespace at the start of the string, and measure its length, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $str = "        for getopts :h opt;; do       #this is just a comment";

$str =~ /^(\s*)/;
my $count = length($1);

say $count;
```

**output**

```
8
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code to find out the count of leading whitespace in `$str`

```
if ($str =~ m/^(\s+)/) {
    $count = length $1;
}
```